# Jquery Clone method increment name tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to add increment in my all form fields from zero to the number whenever I add new clone it assigns the next number to the name tag, I tried all the ways but no any methods works for me.

**Here is my fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/o5wam5r2/

**and here is my JS code**

```
 var formItem;
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //Clone and remove your div instead of hiding it
    formItem = $('.ScheduleextraPartTemplate').clone();
  $('.ScheduleextraPartTemplate').remove();
  formItem.addClass('clone clone-1');
  $('#Schedulecontainer').append(formItem);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '#ScheduleaddRow', function() {
    var cloneForm = $('.clone').last().clone();
  var cloneNum = $('.clone').length;
  cloneForm.removeClass('clone-'+cloneNum).addClass('clone-' + (cloneNum+1));
  var date = cloneForm.find('[name="txtSchedule"]').val();
  cloneForm.find('[name="txtSchedule"]').val(addOneMonth(date));
  $('#Schedulecontainer').append(cloneForm);
 })

function addOneMonth(date) {
    var year = parseInt(date.split("-")[0]);
    var month = parseInt(date.split("-")[1]) + 1;
    var day = parseInt(date.split("-")[2]);
    if(month > 12) {
        month = month - 12;
      year++
    }
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly do you want here

Comment: Do you want to increment name?? Then use '++' method

Comment: Yes i want to increment name

Comment: Add a counter var counter = 0, and on click counter++, and add with name, try this you will get your solution.

Comment: @AtalShrivastava can you please add a sample code related to my code here if possible? I'll be thankful

Comment: var counter = 0;
    $("#addMe").on("click", function(){
                counter++;
                alert(counter);
            });

Comment: hope this will help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x1hdfzab/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing a little piece of code

```
 var formItem;
 var counter = 0;
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //Clone and remove your div instead of hiding it
formItem = $('.ScheduleextraPartTemplate').clone();
  formItem.find('[name^=txtSchedule]')[0].name = "txtSchedule" + counter;
  formItem.find('[name^=txtScheduleAmountPay]')[0].name = "txtScheduleAmountPay" + counter;
$('.ScheduleextraPartTemplate').remove();
  formItem.addClass('clone clone-1');

$('#Schedulecontainer').append(formItem);
});

 $(document).on('click', '#ScheduleaddRow', function() {
    var lens = counter++;
    var cloneForm = $('.clone').last().clone();
  var cloneNum = $('.clone').length;
  cloneForm.removeClass('clone-'+cloneNum).addClass('clone-' + (cloneNum+1));
  var date = cloneForm.find('[name^="txtSchedule"]').val();
  cloneForm.find('[name^="txtSchedule"]').val(addOneMonth(date));
  cloneForm.find('[name^=txtSchedule]')[0].name = "txtSchedule" + (lens+1);
  cloneForm.find('[name^=txtScheduleAmountPay]')[0].name = "txtScheduleAmountPay" + (lens+1);

$('#Schedulecontainer').append(cloneForm);
})

function addOneMonth(date) {
var d = new Date( date );
d.setMonth( d.getMonth( ) + 1 );
return d.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + ((d.getMonth() + 1))).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + (d.getDate())).slice(-2);
}
```